# What is the relationship between the unit simplex and the nonnegative orthant?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I came upon this figure while reading something online.

[image]

Pictured above is the intersection of the unit sphere in the nonnegative orthant and the unit simplex.

Question: What is the relationship between these two sets? Can one set be continuously deformed into another? How about the other way around?

Update: How does Nash Embedding theorem make sense here?

Comment: Yes. They're homemorphic. I edited to point out that the second picture is the *unit sphere* in the nonnegative orthant.

Comment: Sure: just project one onto the other.

Comment: One is distance $1$ from the origin in $L^2$ metric, one in $L^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are homeomorphic by 
$$\varphi(\overline{x})=\frac{\overline{x}}{||\overline{x}||}$$
which is continuous and all, here $\overline{x}=(x,y,z)$ which is the coordinates in questin, as none can be all $0$s there is no issue of it being undefined.